# How do I find the source that is making api calls from my back4app?

Tags: back4app

In my cloud code in my back4app application I do make calls to the google maps api. Everything is working until I restrict the api key in the google api console. I tried adding my back4app url on the whitelist but my calls are getting rejected. While developing i got a 200 dollar bill from google which is surly not me.

How do I find the right source making the calls to be able to restrict the api?

Comment: You can see the last endpoint called of your app (which includes the cloud code function calls) at Dashboard > Cloud Code > Logs > Access. You'll be able to find the IP Address of the origin of each request. If you need a different period, contact the support team and they will help you with that.

Comment: I have added all kind of IP address from the Access panel into the allow list in google developer console. No improvment. Isnt the Access page showing access to the server and not from the server? my code in cloud > main.js is the one calling out to the google maps api.